# How to establish a local maximum if Hessian is negative semi-definite?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, optimization, hessian-matrix

When a Hessian matrix is **negative definite** at a critical point then that critical point is a local maximum (Sufficient Condition). 

As per the calculus wiki:
[Link](https://calculus.subwiki.org/wiki/Second_derivative_test_for_a_function_of_two_variables), when the Hessian is **negative semi-definite** then, we can only conclude that it is not a local minimum. This seems to suggest that negative semi-definiteness is a necessary condition, not a sufficient one. An example of this would be $f(x) = -x^3$

Now if we extend this to multiple variables, and suppose we end up with a negative semi-definite Hessian evaluated at the critical point. In that case, we can only rule out the possibility of the critical point being a local minimum. We still cannot say anything about it being a local max.

Is there a general procedure to conclusively establish if our critical point is a local maximum if the Hessian is **negative semi-definite**, because it may very well be the case that it is not.